# Can i do this accordian like affect in CSS only?

Tags: html, css

This is nearly working. I know i can reach for JS but hopefully no need.

The part i need to get working is when i click on the button again i'd like it to close. Currently if you click anywhere but the button, it closes.

Many thanks.

```css
.drop-down ul{ display:block; max-height:0; visibility:hidden; transition: visibilty 0s, opacity .3s, max-height .3s;}

.drop-down button{ background:none; border:none; position:relative;}

.drop-down button:after{ position:absolute; content:"^"; right:-10px; top:-10px;transform: rotate(180deg);  font-size:1.2em }

.drop-down button:focus:after{ transform: rotate(0deg);pointer-events:none;}

.drop-down button:focus + ul {background-color:green; visibility:visible; max-height:450px}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Level 1 Nav</a></li>
<li class="drop-down">
<button>Level 1 button</button>
  <ul>  
    <li><a href="#">Level 2 Nav</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Level 2 Nav</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
<li><a href="#">Level 1 Nav</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your accordian closes when the button loses focus, which happens when you click anywhere but the button. **When you click on a focused button, it doesn't lose focus, so the only way you can implement the functionality is using JS event listeners (or jQuery).**

If you still want the functionality, assign to your button class `.button`, to your level 2 navigation list class `.level2` and use the following event listener:

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let level2 = document.querySelector('.level2');
  
  if (level2.style.visibility == 'visible') {
    level2.style.display = 'block';
    level2.style.max-height = 0;
    level2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    level2.style.transition = 'visibility 0s, opacity .3s, max-height .3s';
  } else {
    level2.style.background-color = 'green';
    level2.style.visibility = 'visible';
    level2.style.max-height = '450px';
  }
});
```